# Pass multiple list from controller to view

Tags: list, view, model, controller, send

I MVC c# application which has  model

```
 public class lstSearchCriteria
{
    public List<lstCampaign> cmpList { get; set; }
    public List<lstAgent> agentList { get; set; }
}
public class lstCampaign
{
    public string campaignName { get; set; }
}
public class lstAgent
{
    public string agentShortName { get; set; }
    public string agentFullName { get; set; }
}
```

& controller which returns lstSearchCriteria. I need to display lstCampaign & lstAgent in dropdown list.

In view I am doing

```
@using QAApplication.Models
@model QAApplication.Models.lstSearchCriteria

 <select id="lstCampaigns" multiple="multiple">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.cmpList)
                                {
                                    <option >@item.campaignName</option>                                       
                                }
                                </select>
 <div id="divlstAgents">
                            <select id="lstAgents" multiple="multiple">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.agentList)
                                {
                                    <option >@item.agentShortName</option>
                                }
                            </select>
                        </div>
```

I am getting below error :The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[QAApplication.Models.lstSearchCriteria]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'QAApplication.Models.lstSearchCriteria'.

what could be the best way to pass multiple list to view from controller. Thanks in advance

Comment: please add more Information, like wich programming language

Comment: In the controller I was returning List<lstSearchCriteria>. Instead I should return only lstSearchCriteria.  Solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `List<lstSearchCriteria>`, While Views expected model `lstSearchCriteria` only.